# Why do I get permission denied to rmdir a directory created by ditto on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash

I’m using bash with Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). When I type:

```
touch tt
ditto tt foo/bar/tt
```

This creates directory `foo` and `bar`. But I cannot delete it. I try:

```
rm foo/bar/tt
rmdir foo/bar
rmdir: foo/bar: Permission denied
```

Why? I try: `ls -l foo`

```
drwxr-x---+ 3 m114268  MFAD\Domain Users  102 Jun 26 09:59 bar
```

Apparently I am the owner. The only way to delete it is with sudo. Why? And what does that little `+` mean after the mode?

Comment: Can you show output of `umask` command?

Comment: output of umask is 0022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The + states that the file has an access control list, which means there are other users that can / can't access that file, beyond what you're seeing with the initial file attributes. This is likely to be the reason that you can't delete the folder.

You can print the ACL with the -e argument for ls: -

```
ls -e foo
```

You can read more about ACLs [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I type ls -le foo and get "0: group:everyone deny delete" so for some strange reason ditto must have set this permission. It is annoying, I think.